# Jhispter Repository Custom @Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, repository, jhipster, spring-repositories

I have 2 tables in my database, `ProfesorInfo` and `StudentInfo` in a one-to-many relationship. I want to build a custom query to get all students that have a relationship to a certain professor, given the professor's id.
Something like :

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface StudentInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentInfo, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE ProfesorID = profesorId")
    List<StudentInfo> findAllByProfesorID(Long profesorId);
```

The `@Query` doesn't seem to be working. Why is this the case and how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are using the query parameter correctly, it should look something like this:

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
... 
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface StudentInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentInfo, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM StudentInfo s WHERE s.ProfesorID = :profesorId")
    List<StudentInfo> findAllByProfesorID(@Param("profesorId") Long profesorId);
```

The colon tells JPA that the next word is a variable that should be replaced by the value of a `@Param` with the same name.

Imagine a `@Query` as having to navigate, load and filter entities directly in your Java objects. I say this because your field name `ProfesorID` starting with a capital 'P' looks weird. If this field is named `profesorID` in your java entity then it should be named the same when you want to access it inside a jpa query.

If you want more information about this, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#named-parameters) is an excellent guide with examples.

Comment: I was under the impression that by using `@Query` I was interrogating the database directly (not using the JPA classes). Because of that I was using basic SQL. The field name `ProfesorID` doesn't indeed exist in my java entity, it is taken directly from the StudentInfo table in my h2-database. Thank you for the answer !

Comment: No problem, you can actually query the database directly setting `nativeQuery = true`. More info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) (scroll down a bit to native queries).